# Selenium WebDriver select a radio button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to select the first radio button on the page and because I navigated to this page via click a link so I did a `WebDriverWait`. Please see attached picture showing the two radio buttons and code below that execute a wait.

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRw3J.png)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[value='1']"))).click();
```

However I can't click on the first radio button, it will throw this error:

> time out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by.

Comment: If you really want a solution then you need to share HTML code instead of screenshot...

Comment: Rather than posting images of text (HTML, code, etc.), please post the text itself. It will make it easier on those trying to help to reuse the text using copy/paste and will prevent the case where images are lost in the future rendering the question useless. When posting HTML or code, please make sure you properly indent and format them as code. Help on formatting can be found in the How to Format panel on the right side of the editor along with more detailed help contained in the links at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/css-selectors-tutorial-for-selenium-with-examples you can try using .css selector as

```
"input[value=1]"
```

Also you can use a relative xpath instead. Try this code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='1']"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele));
ele.click();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are missing quotes around the `1` value in your CSS selector. It should be `"input[value='1']"`.

Comment: @JeffC, after taking reference from the link in my post and trying it myself, I realized the locator worked without quotes as well. Sounds equally strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking the radio button directly,try clicking the label present next to the radio button. Because sometimes the radio button will not be visible.

try the below xpath expression,

```
//input[@value='1']/following-sibling::label
```

Answer (score 0):

These aren't actual HTML radio buttons, they are just formatted (somewhat) to look like ones. I would click the LABEL

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='Form_Form_Role_1']")).click();
```

or one of the SPAN children.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.radio-txt.supplier")).click();
```

One or both of those should work.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible locator.
`input` won't most probably work, as in most cases from my experience.

Better look by `label`.
Use XPath and search by text, like:

```
//label/span[contains(text(), 'I am supplier')]
```